# Is there a way to stop bookmarks from showing up on searches by switching to a new account?

Tags: google-chrome, user-accounts, bookmarks

So I've been looking for a way to not have bookmarked sites showing on the search bar and after looking around for a bit. I know now that you can't do that so I've been wondering if I can at least solve the problem by switching to the account that I barely use on my phone(account B). When I tried it and logged out of my most frequently used one(account A) on my phone, it didn't work and the bookmarks were still showing up so I've been wondering if I can remove the data and bookmarks on the phone.

My question now is: Is this a viable way of preventing bookmarks from showing up on my search bar when I'm on my phone using chrome?

Something else to note that may also be a problem is I also have both of my accounts(both A and B) logged in on my PC and phone as in I can switch in between accounts on drive, chrome etc. so that might also be a problem if accounts share bookmarks(sorry I don't understand how bookmarks work across accounts on the same device too well)

If anyone else has any other way of stopping bookmarks from showing up at least on my phone when I use chrome that would also be much appreciated if you could share it.

Again thank you so much in advance to anyone that has been willing to read through the explanations and provide me answers. This is a problem that has been bugging me for a long long time(maybe even a few years).

Comment: I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FOClvwyewc) that suggests you can't do it exactly the way you want (it also disables other suggestions) but suggests a plugin that might help